# Javascript get array of string between two quotes

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get array of this result `["13139","13141", "13140"]` from this

```
{
   "13139": [tx[0]],
   "13141": [tx[1]],
   "13140": [tx[2]]
}
```

I tried to `JSON.parse` but it is giving me `TokenError`

Thank you

Comment: `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 1):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Object.keys()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Your input object is not valid JSON so it is a bit more complicated than using `JSON.parse()`. You will have to match values between quotes with a regular expression:

```js
const input = `{"13139":[tx[0]],"13141":[tx[1]],"13140":[tx[2]]}`
input.match(/"(.*?)"/g)

// Result:
[""13139"", ""13141"", ""13140""]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

1. Store the object in a variable for example

```
const obj = {"13139":[tx[0]],"13141":[tx[1]],"13140":[tx[2]]}
```

2. Loop using `for of` like this

```
const arrayFromItems = []
for (let item of Object.keys(obj)) {
    arrayFromItems.push(item)
}
```

3. Now `arrayFromItems` holds an array of the values you looking for.

Comment: Object.keys(obj) will return an array consisting of the keys, so no need to loop through them.